# What it is the VRF coordinator contract on Chainlink?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Im learning Chainlink with solidity but i cant find information about what it is the coordinator contract that is needed to create an instance of VRFConsumerBase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Chainlink VRF Coordinator](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFCoordinator.sol) is a contract that is deployed to a blockchain that will check the randomness of each random number returned from a random node.

You can find the addresses of these contracts on each chain in the [Chainlink documentation under "Contract Addresses"](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/)

[image]

Comment: that's the answer, thanks!